# How to insert million of record in DB within a single transaction using mulesoft 4

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

How to insert million of record in DB within a single transaction using mulesoft 4.
So basically eaither all 1 million records will be inserted into the DB. In case even 1 insert fails, no record will be inserted into the DB.

Comment: What is "mulesoft 4"? Are there 3 more companies called MuleSoft too? Or do you mean Mule 4?

Comment: Have you tried created a transaction of 1 million records with any other product or language and succeed? I'm curious if your database supports that scenario.

Comment: my DB is oracle

Comment: That means very little. Please read: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9542394900346394653